# keyboard works incorrectly for virtualbox ubuntu 15.04 guest in debian jessie host

Tags: debian, ubuntu, virtualbox

When typing in gnome-terminal in ubuntu guest cursor for displayed text periodically shifts left and after 1 second shift back to right showing inputted characters.

When pressing tab console first shows the directories listed, then it shows previous state(before tab was pressed) for couple of seconds and after that shows the correct state.

Things become even worse then using console text editor nano: after shifting to on line to the bottom cursor actually shift two lines to the bottom for couple of seconds then go back.

Text inputted in the browser and gui windows has similar lag too.

Virtualbox version is 4.3.30_debian

I've also found that there is no such lag in not resized xterm window. After xterm window is resized same lag appears there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a need to disable 3d acceleration for the guest.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: Settings/Display/Screen/Acceleration: uncheck enable 3d acceleration